# Excluding certain classes from a thread's context classloader in Java?

Tags: java, classpath, classloader

If I have a program invoked in the following way

```
java -cp a.jar;b.jar;c.jar MainClass
```

All the classes from a.jar, b.jar, and c.jar will be available to all the threads in my program. I'd like to have a thread that is created at some point during my program run with a limited set of classes available, excluding most of the classes in a.jar, b.jar, and c.jar. Is there a way to do this either by adding the required classes to a classloader that doesn't contain everything from the system classpath, or taking a classloader and removing a bunch of classes from it? The only option I currently know of is to write a bootstrap class and load the required classpath for each thread at JVM Initialization. Am I missing something obvious or is bootstrapping my only option?

Comment: Can you use something like http://jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring/2.5.6/spring-2.5.6-sources.jar!/org/springframework/core/OverridingClassLoader.java?format=ok from the spring lib?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom ClassLoader (ie extending URLClassLoader) which throws ClassNotFound exceptions in loadClass(String name) for the classes you do not want on the path. Set this as the contextClassLoader and load the Runnable of the thread from it.